# Does Unity's Project Search Support Regex Anchors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, search, game-engine, game-development

## Goals

Unity has a project search tool like this
[image]

In this project search you can enter text to refine your search like so
[image]

I need to be able to use the regex end anchor tag in order to reduce a bunch of noise for the search. Specifically something like `water1C_*_0$` - where the result is a file that contains the phrase `water1C` AND ends with the `0` character.

## Pre-Existing Research

I have found Unity's search documentation here

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.quicksearch@3.0/manual/index.html

This is nice, but it doesn't seem to help.
It states to use the global search tool using `CMD + K`

However - if I use that search it does not display all the sprites that are created when using a multi sprite image.

This is what I get with the search `water1C`
[image]

When in actually what I want are these results
[image]

And these results are generated using the `Project Search`

---

What's interesting is that the old search documentation here states that there is regex supported.

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.quicksearch@2.1/manual/search-syntax.html

But I cannot get this to work correctly.

## Question

So here it is - my question.

How the heck do I get Unity's `Project Search` bar to filter content using something like regex anchors, where a special character like `$` indicates the end of a file name.

I would like to do this in order to filter specific files and greatly speed up project configuration.

Comment: I digged pretty deep decompiling the `BrojectBrowser` class (that's basically the code behind the Project Window) .. this will lead to the `SearchFilter` and `ProjectSearchSessionHandler` and `IProjectSearchEngine` .. in none of the implementations (on first glance - I didn't read all in detail ^^) I could spot any special "ends with" implementation

Comment: @derHugo - Nooooo. That's a bummer. Do you have a link to this information?

Feel free to respond with this as the answer and I'll mark it. Unity not supporting it is a possible answer!

Comment: There is no link .. just decompiled the the engine core in Rider and glanced roughly through the code ;)